Scroll delay after mouse inactivity
I have a scrolling issue that is driving me nuts on my Windows 10 machine:
Whenever I stop using the mouse for a period of roughly 15-20 seconds or longer and try to scroll up or down on a window, there is a lag of roughly half a second before the input is recognized. Afterwards the lag disappears until there is no input for a longer period.
This issue is present across different programs/windows as well as different mice and touchpad, which leads me to believe it is a Windows-specific setting. I at first thought this might be related to my battery power profile, but unfortunately even after plugging the power cable in the issue persists.
I would really appreciate any pointers into how to solve this.
Many thanks!

If both touchpad and mouse are enabled, that might (or might not) be the casue. Test disabling touchpad: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-touchpad-on-windows-10-home/ebbd7329-b28d-4ab7-ae57-406d2279bcdd

Thanks for the suggestion; No luck unfortunately
